# How to derive the time dependent Leaky Integrator and Fire?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, neural-networks

The general time-dependent LIF model solution is:
$$
u(t) = u_{\text{rest}} \exp \left(-\frac{t-t_0}{\tau_m}\right) + \frac{R}{\tau_m}\int_0^{t-t_0} \exp\left(-\frac{s}{\tau_m}\right) \, I(t-s) \,\mathrm d s
$$
From the LIF equation 
$$
\tau_m \frac{du}{dt}  = R I(t) - [u(t) - u_{\text{rest}}] 
$$
According to this [paper](http://www.cns.nyu.edu/~eorhan/notes/lif-neuron.pdf), equation 7.

It is assumed $t_0$ is the beginning of the time interval, at which $u(t)$ is at it's minimum and that $I(t)$ can vary. I have no idea where to even start, thank you.

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly are you asking? Do you want to understand how to solve LIF equation?

Comment: Yes, or a step by step derivation of the general LIF so that I can understand it.